# How do I detect if have to apply UTF-8 decode or encode on a string?

Tags: php, encoding, utf-8

I have a feed taken from third-party sites, and sometimes I have to apply `utf8_decode` and other times `utf8_encode` to get the desired visible output.

If by mistake the same stuff is applied twice/or the wrong method is used I get something more ugly, this is what I want to change.

How can I detect when what have to apply on the string?

Actually the content returns UTF-8, but inside there are parts that are not.

Comment: Should we assume that the feed declares certain charset but uses another one?

Comment: please provide an example feed please

Answer (score 66, accepted):

I can't say I can rely on `mb_detect_encoding()`. I had some freaky false positives a while back.

The most universal way I found to work well in every case was:

```
if (preg_match('!!u', $string))
{
   // This is UTF-8
}
else
{
   // Definitely not UTF-8
}
```

Comment: +1 Implemented a utf8_validate() that uses your solution to convert a string to utf8 if it isn't, works as a charm!

Comment: Thank you! That's a very clever trick ;-) Since I had absolutely no friggin' clue how it worked, I delved into the PHP documentation to find [this](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

`u (PCRE8)
    This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern is checked since PHP 4.3.5. `

Anyway, thanks a bunch!

Comment: that dot in regexp is not even needed `preg_match('!!u', $str)` works ok

Comment: That dot will make it even return 0 (equals false) for empty strings. But empty strings are valid UTF-8 ;).

Comment: "It's just an empty regular expression. ! is the delimiter and u is the modfier." The solution is indeed clever, but needed some more verbose explanation, so I asked about it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855682/explain-this-utf-8-detection-regex

Comment: Yupp, had a false positive right now on a pretty obvious CSV file. This solution works.

Answer (score 7):

```
function str_to_utf8 ($str) {
    $decoded = utf8_decode($str);
    if (mb_detect_encoding($decoded , 'UTF-8', true) === false)
        return $str;
    return $decoded;
}

var_dump(str_to_utf8("« Chrétiens d'Orient » : la RATP fait marche arrière"));
//string '« Chrétiens d'Orient » : la RATP fait marche arrière' (length=56)
var_dump(str_to_utf8("Â« ChrÃ©tiens d'Orient Â» : la RATP fait marche arriÃ¨re"));
//string '« Chrétiens d'Orient » : la RATP fait marche arrière' (length=56)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use

- [`mb_detect_encoding`](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) — Detect character encoding

The character set might also be available in the [HTTP response headers](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) or in the response data itself.

Example:

```
var_dump(
    mb_detect_encoding(
        file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407854')
    ),
    $http_response_header
);
```

Output ([codepad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Pntxh4)):

```
string(5) "UTF-8"
array(9) {
  [0]=>
  string(15) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK"
  [1]=>
  string(33) "Cache-Control: public, max-age=11"
  [2]=>
  string(38) "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"
  [3]=>
  string(38) "Expires: Fri, 10 Dec 2010 10:40:07 GMT"
  [4]=>
  string(44) "Last-Modified: Fri, 10 Dec 2010 10:39:07 GMT"
  [5]=>
  string(7) "Vary: *"
  [6]=>
  string(35) "Date: Fri, 10 Dec 2010 10:39:55 GMT"
  [7]=>
  string(17) "Connection: close"
  [8]=>
  string(21) "Content-Length: 34119"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The feed (I guess you mean some kind of XML-based feed) should have an attribute in the header telling you what the encoding is. If not, you are out of luck as you don't have a reliable means of identifying the encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Encoding autotection is not bullet-proof but you can try `mb_detect_encoding()`. See also `mb_check_encoding()`.