# How to decide when to uft8_encode, uft8_decode or do nothing when dealing with french characters?

Tags: php, encoding, special-characters

I am trying to build a function in php that will take the input of a string and encode it correctly before displaying it. So far I have:

```
public function encode($str)
{
  if(!preg_match('!!u', $str)) // Needs to be encoded
  {  
    $str = "YES: " . $str;
    $str = utf8_encode($str);        
  } 
  else 
  {
    $str = "NO: " . $str;
  }
  return $str;
}
```

The if statement I am using i found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407854/how-to-detect-if-have-to-apply-utf8-decode-or-encode-on-a-string). And it works in some cases but in others it is encoding the string when they shouldn't be.

Perhaps there is an easier way to handle the encoding ?

Comment: What is your situation, what are you encoding for what purpose, where is the data coming from? Pointing you to the default question & answer on the topic, hold on

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: How does [mb_detect_encoding](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) work for you?